# Can you disable a trigger within a trigger? SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

Can you disable and re-enable triggers within a trigger?

For example, I have a piece of information in a front-end application that can be put in one of two places. If someone puts it in place A, I want to copy it to place B and vice versa.

So, my idea is to put two triggers on the different tables 1) When it's put in A it puts it in B. 2) When it's put in B it puts it in A

This would create a neverending loop (I assume?) so can you disable Trigger 1 while Trigger 2 runs and enable it at the end?

Comment: You shouldn't do so - what if connection 1 has just done an insert on table A - the trigger disables the trigger on table B - now connection 2 does an insert there, and the trigger doesn't fire.

Comment: Whenever you're thinking of duplicating data in a database, you ought to be asking yourself whether the model is correct in the first place - ought A and B to be two views built on top of a single table, for example?

Comment: I agree with you 99 times out of 100. The reason for having it in 2 locations is because one is a field in the front end over-writeable by anyone, and the other is a fixed, "view only" area (as in it's viewable like a grid). People are too lazy to put the data in both areas, so I'm trying to think of a way of automatically copying data from one to the other and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I agree with Damien's comment that duplicating data in two tables in the same database is generally undesirable, if you really have a good reason for doing this then you could use [`INSTEAD OF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) triggers instead of `AFTER` triggers (which I assume you're looking at now). That way you can 'replace' a single `INSERT` with two separate `INSERTs` that you code and control yourself.

Comment: Thanks - hadn't come across INSTEAD OF triggers, so that looks like it would do the trick very nicely!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename DISABLE TRIGGER triggername
ALTER TABLE tablename ENABLE TRIGGER triggername
```

Although, for your solution, I'd create a trigger that runs the same on each side, and is clever enough not to mess itself up.

i.e. Make the trigger intelligently distinguish between a user/client INSERT and a trigger 'MOVE'.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could check whether the information had changed in the trigger before doing the update, which would end the loop?